# Cant Change UIView Background Color From Black

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, colors, draw

This is my first time in which I've encountered problems with drawRect. I have a simple UIView subclass with a path to fill. Everything is fine. The path gets filled properly, but the background remains black no matter what. What should I do? My code is listed below:

```
var color: UIColor = UIColor.red {didSet{setNeedsDisplay()}}

private var spaceshipBezierPath: UIBezierPath{
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let roomFromTop: CGFloat = 10
    let roomFromCenter: CGFloat = 7
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY+roomFromTop))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX-roomFromCenter, y: bounds.minY+roomFromTop))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX-roomFromCenter, y: bounds.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX+roomFromCenter, y: bounds.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX+roomFromCenter, y: bounds.minY+roomFromTop))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.minY+roomFromTop))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
    return path
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    color.setFill()
    spaceshipBezierPath.fill()
}
```

Here is what the view looks like: 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe add a `path.close()` before return path in spaceshipBezierPath

Comment: Nope. Tried that but didn't work. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Nikhi Sridhar, I use your code to draw the rect but get the color, your red is blue in my view, your black is white.  and what effect do you want to get?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I have a simple UIView subclass ... but the background remains black no matter what

Typically that sort of thing is because you have forgotten to set the UIView subclass's `isOpaque` to `false`. It is a good idea to do this *in the UIView subclass's initializer* in order for it to be early enough.

For example, here I've adapted your code very slightly. This is the complete code I'm using:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    private var spaceshipBezierPath: UIBezierPath{
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // ... identical to your code
        return path
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        spaceshipBezierPath.fill()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        let v = MyView(frame:CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
        self.view.addSubview(v)
    }
}
```

Notice the black background:

[image]

Now I add these lines to MyView:

```
override init(frame:CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.isOpaque = false
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

See the difference that makes?

[image]

Comment: Would it be a valid alternative to set `isOpaque` in `willMove(toSuperview)` e.g.?

Comment: @andreas1724 Absolutely, I think so — if it is called for your situation. That should be "early enough" too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what I solved was to switch from Background-Color "No Color", to Background-Color "Clear Color"

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers....

I had the same problem but @matt solution didn’t work for me.

In my scenario, I had a UIView (A) behind another UIView (B).
UIView (A) had a **background color** and UIView (B) was transparent. Worth to note that B was subclassed to create a custom shape using `UIBezier` by overriding `draw` method.

Turned out that in this situation a transparent UIView means nothing and I had to set the same background color for B or either remove background color of A.

**there was no other way, so don’t waste your time if you have the same scenario!**