# UIView background color always BLACK while drawing UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath, shapes

I'm adding ShapeView which is subclass of UIView to View Controller in which I'm drawing Bezier Path and the background of that view always stays black. I tried to fix my problem with answers from [UIView Background Color Always Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593250/uiview-background-color-always-black) and [Cant Change UIView Background Color From Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41666227/cant-change-uiview-background-color-from-black) but, unfortunately, no results.

The gradient green is shape, and the black areas under shape should be white.

[image]

Here is code from ShapeView class.

```swift
class ShapeView: UIView {

    //// Color Declarations
    // Green - Storage
    let gradientColor0 = UIColor(red: 0.082, green: 0.608, blue: 0.486, alpha: 1.000)
    let gradientColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.502, green: 0.980, blue: 0.949, alpha: 1.000)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.isOpaque = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        //// Gradient Declarations
        let paint0_linear2 = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: [gradientColor0.cgColor, gradientColor1.cgColor] as CFArray, locations: [0, 1])!

        //// Bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 342))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 187.5, y: 372))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 342))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 342))
        bezierPath.close()
        bezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        context.saveGState()
        bezierPath.addClip()
        context.drawLinearGradient(paint0_linear2,
                                   start: CGPoint(x: 363.75, y: -664.71),
                                   end: CGPoint(x: 900.13, y: 234.82),
                                   options: [.drawsBeforeStartLocation, .drawsAfterEndLocation])
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Try setting `colorsSpace` to `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB`.

Comment: Set view.isOpaque = false and you got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add those two lines to `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` just after `super.draw(rect)`:

```swift
UIColor.white.setFill()
UIRectFill(rect)
```

so the method looks like this:

```swift
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)

    //// General Declarations
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!



    //// Gradient Declarations
    let paint0_linear2 = CGGradient(colorsSpace: nil, colors: [gradientColor0.cgColor, gradientColor1.cgColor] as CFArray, locations: [0, 1])!

    //// Bezier Drawing
    let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 342))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 187.5, y: 372))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 342))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 375, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 342))
    bezierPath.close()
    bezierPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    context.saveGState()
    bezierPath.addClip()
    context.drawLinearGradient(paint0_linear2,
                               start: CGPoint(x: 363.75, y: -664.71),
                               end: CGPoint(x: 900.13, y: 234.82),
                               options: [.drawsBeforeStartLocation, .drawsAfterEndLocation])
    context.restoreGState()
}
```

If you need other background-colour you can change `white` in: `UIColor.white.setFill()` to needed colour.

Comment: Or you can just set view.isOpaque = false

Answer (score 2):

You may find this much easier to work with...

```
@IBDesignable
class JurkoShapeView: UIView {

    override open class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.classForCoder()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        if let l = layer as? CAGradientLayer {

            let gradientColor0 = UIColor(red: 0.082, green: 0.608, blue: 0.486, alpha: 1.000)
            let gradientColor1 = UIColor(red: 0.502, green: 0.980, blue: 0.949, alpha: 1.000)

            l.colors = [gradientColor0.cgColor, gradientColor1.cgColor]
            l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        }

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let l = CAShapeLayer()

        let y1 = bounds.size.height - 30

        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: 0))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: y1))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.maxY))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y1))
        bezierPath.close()

        l.path = bezierPath.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = l

    }
}
```

By making it `@IBDesignable` you can see it while designing in Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: I was about to add a comment to my response that it is better to use `CAGradientLayer` and mask it with `CAShapeLayer`, but @DonMag already did it.

Comment: What is the meaning of `lazy var gradientLayer`? I mean you never used it.

Comment: @LeoDabus - whoops... was from an older approach (that got left in)... edited my answer and removed it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DonMag . I rewrited my code to your version, It's much easier to use and you saved me time for fixing Bezier drawing from static points to dynamic points depended by view size.